# Installable typescript type definitions for an npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package, typescript-typings

Typings are one the best features of Typescript and I find it very useful, to adopt it all over the javascript project, however the usage and best practices are not documented very efficient that causes a lot of confusion for the developers.

For example my npm package named `my-awesome-pkg` and for this package we are interested to have @typings, that users are able to install it using npm `npm install @types/my-awesome-pkg`

I know how to use `include` or `files` in `tsconfig.json` to include and use the @typings in your project :

`"include": [ "< path to your typing file>" ]`

But that is not my what I am looking for, I am interested to know, how to create installable @typings for my project, so users don't get frustrated looking for the typings of my npm package, as assume there is an standard practice for doing it.

Thanks,

Comment: If you author the definitions for you own package it is preferred to bundle them with your package instead of contributing to @types. See [the relevant section at DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#create-a-new-package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in case that your project is written in TypeScript all you have to do is to set the following flags in your project's `tsconfig.json`:

```
"declaration": true,
"declarationDir": './anyFolderYouLike'
```

This will generate types for your TypeScript project when `tsc` is run. For further information on how to configure the `tsc` see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Many people host their types on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). That way one should be able to install the types the way you wish to.

I am seeing more and more folks delivering their types with their own package though. This way there is no need to install them separately. If you want to do it that way you should specify the types location in the `package.json`, i.e.:

```
"types": "./lib/index.d.ts"
```

For further overall information on publishing please refer to the [TypeScript publishing documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information, you are right, it is better to include the typings within the project, I am going to do the same.

Comment: For the ts callers of your package to see your type definitions in editors, they have to use the syntax `import myAwesomePkg = require('my-awesome-pkg')` as opposed to commonJS syntax `let myAwesomePkg = require('my-awesome-pkg')`.